# Write a program to do something on some other's website, is it impossible to do that?

Tags: javascript, c#, python, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Generally, I open some other's website in the browser, say google.com, type something in the search box then click search.

Is it impossible to write a program to do that and find something on the result page, instead of doing that manually?

I tried javascript but there seems no way to go around the same-origin restriction.

PS: Not only search, maybe I also need to input username, password and login.
Besides javascript, I'm using C#.

Comment: Is this just for your personal use? You might want to look at browser extensions.

Comment: maybe you can write into the url...

Comment: use tampermonkey and greasemonkey for that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this in C# (winforms). Firstly, you need to create an instance of Internet explorer browser and then initialise  its parameters, say like its size , position , URL(www.google.com) etc. URL specifies the website that should be loaded in IE browser.

After this you need to create a function which handle controls in the website(www.google.com).Make sure that this function gets called only after the website
 is loaded completely. You can use event handlers for this.

Source code:-
Create browser instance

```
this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
```

Initializing browser parameters

```
this.webBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(903, 448);
this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
// specify your url here
this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("www.google.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

Create event handler

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

Handle controls in the website:

```
//sets user name text box to ganesh  
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("username")[0].SetAttribute("Value", "ganesh");
```

Comment: I would highly encourage you to go through webbrowser control in winforms(visual studio).

Answer (score 0):

Really the only way to do this is with a proxy server, but you can create one very easily in javascript with node:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);

function onRequest(client_req, client_res) {
  console.log('serve: ' + client_req.url);

  var options = {
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: client_req.url,
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.pipe(client_res, {
      end: true
    });
  });

  client_req.pipe(proxy, {
    end: true
  });
}
```

The above code will return google's home page.  Since your own local server is returning the page, you no longer have to worry about cross domain issues and are free to use the data however you like.